# Как проверить работоспособность функции и если работает заблокировать event('click')

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 функции которые выполняются каждую секунду и 2 кнопки которые запускают и останавливают эти функции, с кнопкой `stop` всё хорошо она без проблем работает, но когда нажимаю несколько раз подряд `start` функция начинает уменьшать интервал выполнения с каждым нажатием, отсюда 2 вопроса:

1. Как сделать чтобы кнопка start не была доступна, пока работают
   функции и не нажата кнопка stop, а после нажатия stop её можно было
   нажать 1 раз(чтобы функции setInterval работали корректно)?
2. Можно ли сделать так чтобы кнопки обе работали(без нарушения setInterval) и их можно было нажать только по одному разу на чистом
   js без Jquery?

   ```
    const mySetDate = setInterval(setDate, 1000);
   const mySetBg = setInterval(backgr, 1000);
   const stopButton = document.querySelector("button[value=stop]");
   const startButton = document.querySelector("button[value=go]");
   startButton.addEventListener('click', myStartFunction);
   stopButton.addEventListener('click', myStopFunction);

   function myStopFunction() {
     clearInterval(mySetDate);
     clearInterval(mySetBg);
   }

   function myStartFunction(e) {
     setInterval(setDate, 1000);
     setInterval(backgr, 1000);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не "функция уменьшает интервал", а еще одно выполнение запускается с тем же интервалом, и они начинают вызываться вперемешку.

```js
const mySetDate = setInterval(setDate, 1000);
const mySetBg = setInterval(backgr, 1000);

const stopButton = document.querySelector("button[value=stop]");
const startButton = document.querySelector("button[value=go]");
startButton.addEventListener('click', myStartFunction);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', myStopFunction);

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(mySetDate);
  mySetDate = null;
  clearInterval(mySetBg);
  mySetBg = null;
}

function myStartFunction(e) {
  if (!mySetDate)
    mySetDate = setInterval(setDate, 1000);
  if (!mySetBg)
    mySetBg = setInterval(backgr, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allowStart = true;
function myStopFunction(){
    if(allowStart) return;
    clearInterval(mySetDate);
    clearInterval(mySetBg);
    allowStart = true;
}

function myStartFunction(e){
    if(!allowStart) return;
    setInterval(setDate, 1000);
    setInterval(backgr, 1000);
    allowStart = false;
}
```